# How can I use \if \then \else with \@ifclassloaded{}

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, pgffor

I wrote a package that uses the `\@ifclassloaded{}` command to handle the document class, like,

```
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter%
\@ifclassloaded{book}
{%
<code block>
}
\makeatother%

\makeatletter%
\@ifclassloaded{article}
{%
<code block>
}
\makeatother%
```

I want to handle the `report` or `memoir` class with `book` class in same conditional, like that:

```
\makeatletter%
\@ifclassloaded{book}
\else  \@ifclassloaded{report}
\else  \@ifclassloaded{memoir} 
{%
<code block>
}
\makeatother%
```

but not work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `etoolbox` and its `\ifboolexpr` command to combine several conditionals of the form `\<conditional [possibly with additional arguments]>{<true>}{<false>}` into one.

Note the `test` keyword in front of each conditional and the braces around them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\test}{} % just to make sure \test is undefined

\makeatletter
\ifboolexpr{   test {\@ifclassloaded{book}}
            or test {\@ifclassloaded{report}}
            or test {\@ifclassloaded{memoir}}}
  {\def\test{lorem}}
  {\def\test{ipsum}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

---

In this example you could also directly test for the existence of the `\chapter` command. Depending on what you are trying to do that may actually be the better idea.

Here I used `\ifundef` from `etoolbox`, this reverses the logic from the first example. (There is also `\ifdef`, but that treats commands that are `\relax` as defined, which isn't that useful for this application.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\test}{} % just to make sure \test is undefined

\ifundef\chapter
  {\def\test{ipsum}}
  {\def\test{lorem}}


\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second option (`\ifundef\chapter`) is more useful for me.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax of `\@ifclassloaded` is

```
\@ifclassloaded{class}{yes code}{no code}
```

so you do not need `\else`. Both branches are built in to the syntax.

You have

```
\@ifclassloaded{book}
{%
<code block>
}
\makeatother%
```

so your "no code" argument is `\makeatother` so you only execute that if the class is not book.

You should never have `\makeatletter` or `\makeatother` in a package code anyway so your fragment should look like

```
\RequirePackage{pgffor}

\@ifclassloaded{book}
{%
<code block>
}{%
 else code
}

\@ifclassloaded{article}
{%
<code block>
}{%
    else code
}
```

Incidentally checking for class by name isn't really recommended, there are thousands of classes and if someone makes one by copying `book.cls` and changing a few things, your package will not recognise it as a book-like class. It is usually better to test for specific features like `\chapter` being defined rather than checking that the class is called `book`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. According to @moewe's answer, I've already rearranged my code for `\chapter` control. Also, I will take your suggestions into consideration.

Comment: @ferahfeza yes I saw moewe had answered but I wanted to make sure that this post  included an answer highlighting that you were only supplying two of the three arguments of  `\@ifclassloaded`  in case future readers copy the code.

Comment: That's why I love this site. Both of you answers are very descriptive. For both me and future readers. Thank you again.